# Configure cassandra 3.11.2 to accept remote connection on ec2

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Hey guys i tried many of the solutions posted on different sites and stackoverflow too, but none of them worked for me.
I have eximented with the following cassandra.yaml paramters-

1. rpc_address
2. rpc_broadcast_address
3. listen_address

Most of the solutions are out dated, little help is highly appreciated

Comment: What is the error that you encounter?

Comment: 'Unable to connect to any servers, connection refused

Comment: Share the output of "nodetool status" and "netstat -an | grep 9042"? This will ensure Cassandra is running

Comment: nodetool status- Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: netstat -an | grep 9042 returns nothing

Comment: when i change listen_address to private ec2 ip then things don't work but when set to localhost things work like charm

Comment: what is the listen address port in yaml ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170576/discussion-between-vishal-chaurasia-and-dilsingi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in chat, there was a typo while adding private ip address for listen_address in the cassandra.yaml. Due to this error, Cassandra never got started and hence no output for the following commands.

```
nodetool status
  - Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)

netstat -an | grep 9042 
  - returns nothing
```

As always, the first place to look at the errors is cassandra system log. And it clearly indicated the following problem.

```
ERROR [main] 2018-05-08 02:01:26,541 CassandraDaemon.java:708 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassan$ 
Error: while scanning a simple key; could not found expected ':'; in 'reader', line 678, column 1: 
# Set rpc_address OR rpc_interfa ...
```

After fixing the ":" error in cassandra.yaml file, Cassandra came up smoothly.